# Angular: How to use custom function inside the ng-repeat directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my Template:

```
...
<tr data-ng-dblclick="getCandidateInfo()"
    data-ng-class="{'black-list': candidate.bl}"
    data-ng-repeat="candidate in candidates | orderBy : orderByField : reverseSort">
    <td >{{candidate.fullnameEN}}</td>
    <td>{{candidate.birthDate}}</td>
    <td>{{candidate.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{candidate.email}}</td>
    <td>{{candidate.skype}}</td>
    <td><span ng-show="candidate.bl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
</tr>
...
```

Question: how to apply custom function **convertDate()** to {{ candidate.birthDate }} inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to either use the built in "[date `$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)" or if you are doing something VERY unique and the "date `$filter`" is not good enough for you, then you could create your own `$filter`, like this:

```
app.filter('convertDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        if (!date) return "";
        var result;
        //your code here    
        return result;
    };
});
```

And you could use it like this in your template:

```
{{candidate.birthDate | convertDate}}
```

Comment: It would be {{candidate.birthDate | convertDate}}

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it...

define a function in your controller as :

```
$scope.convertDate = function(date){
   var convertedDate;
   //convert date here and assign to convertedDate
   return convertedDate;
}
```

then in view ,

```
<td>{{convertDate(candidate.birthDate)}}</td>
```

Comment: I would really recommend you not to do it like this, it's a very bad practice to use functions for formatting the Model inside the View. Angular has $filters for that purpose. By using $filters your code will be easier to maintain, easier to test and easier to reuse.

Comment: You are right.. it's just another way of achieving the target :) not really a best practice though.

Comment: Thanks, but prev.solution is a little better as for me.